# I want to return top 4 highest salaries from each dept along with deptno and dname in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to return top 4 highest salaries from each dept along with deptno and dname in a stored procedure.
when deptno is not included there is no error but 
When including deptno im getting an error invalid number.
ORA-01722: invalid number
Here is the code

```
    create or replace procedure tpro2(dno in emp.deptno%type,dnum out dept.deptno%type, name out emp.ename%type, sal out emp.sal%type,dname out dept.dname%type, cur out sys_refcursor)
    is begin
    open cur for select ename , sal, dname, dept.deptno from (select * from emp order by sal desc)emp, dept where emp.deptno=dept.deptno and emp.deptno=dno and rownum<=4;
    end tpro2;
    /

   declare
   dnum dept.deptno%type;
   name emp.ename%type;
   sal emp.sal%type;
   dname dept.dname%type;
   cur sys_refcursor;
   begin
   tpro2(&dno,dnum,name,sal,dname,cur);
   loop
   fetch cur into dnum,name,sal,dname;
   exit when cur%notfound;
   dbms_output.put_line(dnum||'  '||name||'  '||sal||'  '||dname);
   end loop;
   close cur;
   end;
   /
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
open cur for select ename, sal, dname, dept.deptno 
fetch cur into dnum, name, sal, dname;
```

Does you see nothing suspicious here? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [**window functions**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23sql-1906475.html) to get the information you need without writing a stored procedure at all:

```
SELECT ename, sal, dname, deptno
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY sal DESC) "Rank"
  FROM emp e inner join dept d using (deptno)
```